# google maps pin api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have got a google map loading on my website using the api. I have styled it how I would like but I need to add a pin with custom image to a location on my map. The center co-ordinatres are different of those that I would like to use for the pin. I have tried using the code supplied in the google api docs but cannot seem to get it to work. below is the code I am using now without the pin code as it wasn't working. Would someone be able to tell me what to add to get the pin working for an image file called:

```
'pin.png'
```

and the co-ordinates:

```
51.4531807,-2.1864739,17
```

here is my current JS

```
              // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

        function init() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
            var office = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4477764,-2.2015512);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: office,
  map: map
});
            // Basic options for a simple Google Map
            // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
            var mapOptions = {
                // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                zoom: 17,

                // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4476895, -2.2057354), // New York

                draggable: false,
                 zoomControl: false,
                  scrollwheel: false,
                   disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                   streetViewControl: false,
                   disableDefaultUI: true,

                // How you would like to style the map. 
                // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                styles: [   {       featureType:'water',        elementType:'all',      stylers:[           {hue:'#bbbbbb'},            {saturation:-100},          {lightness:-4},         {visibility:'on'}       ]   },{     featureType:'landscape',        elementType:'all',      stylers:[           {hue:'#999999'},            {saturation:-100},          {lightness:-33},            {visibility:'on'}       ]   },{     featureType:'road',     elementType:'all',      stylers:[           {hue:'#999999'},            {saturation:-100},          {lightness:-6},         {visibility:'on'}       ]   },{     featureType:'poi',      elementType:'all',      stylers:[           {hue:'#aaaaaa'},            {saturation:-100},          {lightness:-15},            {visibility:'on'}       ]   },{
featureType: 'poi.business',
elementType: 'labels',
stylers: [
  { visibility: 'off' }
]
 }]
            };



            // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
            // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

            // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above

        }
```

Comment: you try to draw a pin on a map and post everything except the code that should draw the pin...hard to help.

Comment: I have added this now. Sorry.

Comment: move the code for the  marker to the end of `init() `  (currently it's placed outside where `map` is not accessible)

Comment: I moved the code to directly under function init () { and it still won't work. I have updated the code in the post

Comment: the end of the function is after that line: `// Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above`

Comment: Ahh! it is working now thank you. How can I define a custom image?

Answer (score 0):

The code to display the pin on the map was correct however this was outside of where the map is accessible. To rectify this issue the code had to be put after the map and before the closing bracket as displayed by @Dr.Molle

```
var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');


          var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
            var hadston = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4477764,-2.2015512);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: hadston,
  map: map,
clickable: false,
  icon: 'pin.png'
  }); 
        }
```

To display a custom pin I used icon with a direct link to the image.

```
 icon: 'pin.png'
```